# What is the process to allocate certain amount of the RAM to Rstudio on Ubuntu

Tags: ram, r

As I am an Ubuntu beginner, this question is about managing R on Ubuntu. I have increased RAM from 4 GB to 16 GB. But sadly spending a month on this problem I still get the error:

```
can not allocate a vector of 600 MB
```

I have gone through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes that has the needed answer for Windows. What is the process to allocate all 14 GB of my memory to Rstudio on Ubuntu.

```
sessionInfo() R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: There is no way to do it, nor does it make much sense to. Allocating all of RAM to just two programs would render the whole system unusable.

Comment: @mikewhatever kindly help me understand what do you mean?

Comment: @mikewhatever ok. How do I allocate 14 GB to Rstudio in Ubuntu?

Comment: Is this your own machine, or one that is provided by an employer or institution? what is the output of `ulimit -v` from a bash shell?

Comment: @mikewhatever Well I have been granted to do whatever possible to solve the problem on this system. output of ulimit -v from terminal: unlimited

Comment: unlimited means rstudio has access to the full 14Gb (and so has any other program).

Comment: @Rinzwind Then why I am getting the vector allocation error. This question shows it is due to limited RAM   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: Increasing ram is not the answer. Your problem is with R and not Ubuntu. Did you not get a notice about `warnings()` when you got that error? I bet it shows something like "Reached total allocation of xxxxMb: see help(memory.size) " and `memory.limit()` shows what the max is. and `memory.limit(size=nnnnnn)` sets it to nnnnnn.

Comment: @Rinzwind I get Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific  for memory.limit

Comment: @Rinzwind When I do what you suggest: memory.limit(size=nnnnnn)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific

Comment: @Rinzwind Kindly suggest a solution :(

Comment: if your physical memory is 16GB and R is choking when creating a vector of only 600MB, then there must be something you're not telling us.  Are there other memory-intensive applications running in the background?  Are there other objects being created in your R workspace before your script hits the line that throws the error?  Does this happen if you close all programs, open a fresh R session, and just try `foo <- rnorm(100000000)` (which should be about 800MB, cf. `object.size(foo)`)?